# Structuring knockoutjs viewmodels and server calls properly

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and today have succesfully put together a page with some binding and a couple of ajax calls. It's fun stuff!

Now that I have those basic functions working, I need to consider whats coming next.

The situation:

I have a 'settings' page with 4 tabs on it. Each tab will have some input fields, basic form elements, but all of them will be bound via knockout, and data will go back and forth using asp.net WebApi and ajax.

The question is, how can I structure my current viewmodel to make sure I am not running into some roadblocks when I start integrating the other tabs on the page?

Here is my current full viewmodel:

```
function UserSettingsViewModel(apiBaseUrl, userId) {
var self = this;
self.firstName = ko.observable();
self.lastName = ko.observable();
self.primaryEmail = ko.observable();
self.secondaryEmail = ko.observable();
self.addressCity = ko.observable();
self.addressPostalCode = ko.observable();
self.addressCounty = ko.observable();
self.addressCountry = ko.observable();

self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
}, this);

$.getJSON(apiBaseUrl + "?userId=" + userId, function (data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    self.firstName(data.FirstName);
    self.lastName(data.LastName);
    self.primaryEmail(data.PrimaryEmail);
    self.secondaryEmail(data.SecondaryEmail);
    self.addressCity(data.City);
    self.addressPostalCode(data.PostalCode);
    self.addressCounty(data.County);
    self.addressCountry(data.Country);
});

self.updateName = function () {
    alert('in update name method!');
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: apiBaseUrl + "?userId=" + userId,
        data: ko.toJSON({
            UserGuid: userId,
            FirstName: self.firstName(),
            LastName: self.lastName(),
            PrimaryEmail: self.primaryEmail(),
            SecondaryEmail: self.secondaryEmail(),
            City: self.addressCity(),
            PostalCode: self.addressPostalCode(),
            County: self.addressCounty(),
            Country: self.addressCountry()
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
};
}
```

And in the view itself I am doing a little bit:

```
ko.applyBindings(new UserSettingsViewModel('@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", 
new { httproute = "httproute", controller = "Settings" })', userId));
```

Again, I am a beginner (haven't touched this stuff for over a year and I wasn't very good at it then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "top-level" ViewModel and make the individual tab ViewModels properties of it. Also look into the mapping plugin to reduce the amount of repetitious and error-prone code involved in constructing and serializing the individual ViewModels.

Your top-level VM should contain an `observable` that's used by a `template` binding in your settings page to pick the appropriate template for each tab's contents.

UPDATE

Example of "top-level" VM:

```
var vm={
  userSettings: new UserSettingsViewModel(...),
  readPreferences: new ReadPreferencesViewModel(...),
  sharePreferences: new SharePreferencesViewModel(...),
  activeTab: ko.observable('user-settings')
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Where `userSettings`, `readPreferences` and `sharePreferences` are VMs for individual tabs, and `activeTab` specifies the id of the template to use for the currently-shown tab.

The Knockout documentation for the `template` binding is excellent.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'top-level' vm? I know the page itself will need about 2-3 viewmodels like the one I have, so it sounds like what I would need. I'll need to look up template binding, does the knockout site have a decent coverage of it? Any recommended reading?